# MySQL suddenly disk I/O high after just midnight

Tags: mysql

I execute 8,400 INSERT command every seconds, and 1,400 SELECT commands every hours.
My database server is usually a few I/O wait, but, it suddenly I/O high after just midnight like below (vmstat command),

```
-----time---- -----io----
23:59:55 288 50452
23:59:56 320 43986
23:59:57 336 27018
23:59:58 512 27658
23:59:59 592 42305
00:00:00 50656 43240
00:00:01 129072 23721
00:00:02 128472 18160
00:00:03 128600 52498
00:00:04 128560 37964
00:00:05 129408 21136
00:00:06 133320 19158
00:00:07 42864 46117
00:00:08 282752 46846
00:00:09 284992 42096
00:00:10 272880 42359
00:00:11 16 49306
```

It happens every day. My execution code will slow down.

A database server is having 72 GB ram
and, parameter current value

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=54G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=54
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commi=0
innodb_io_capacity=5000
innodb_io_capacity_max=1000
innodb_read_io_threads=32
innodb_write_io_threads=24
```

Why does it happen?
Please suggest if you find anything wrong.

Comment: Have you checked slow logs for that duration?

Comment: Is there an automatic backup at midnight?

Comment: check cron jobs if anything schedule there  for midnight